# MySQL database structure: more columns or more rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I collect how people tag topics with categories in table like:

```
ID | topic_id | votes_Category_1 | votes_Category_2 |.......... | votes_Category_12
```

I dump this table every hour for history reasons.
Lets say table contain 2 million rows. dumped every hour in history tables.

This solution is not flexible if I want to add column Category_13, so I'm thinking about this one:

```
ID | topic_id | Category_id | vote_count
```

This solution will create 12 rows per topic, its better structured and more flexible but I'll have to dump every hour 24 million rows.

I need the best 10 topics in each category!
I wonder in Case 2 if using Max on votes (where category_id=x and topic_id=y) will be slower than in case 1: Order by categoy_x where topic_id=y

Which one would be better JUST!!! from performance stand point:

1. To have 2 million rows with 14 columns
2. To have 24 million rows with 4 columns

Thank you

Comment: Actually a good example for switching to NoSQL database. :-)

Comment: Don't forget that option1 +the sorting by votes_category_xxx will need XXX indexes. The normalised version (option2) will have a constant number of indexes/ key constraints.

Answer (score 4):

I would look at the retrieval patterns to decide on the approach.

1. If you retrieve the topics by category, then I would go with the second approach, define index on the category field so that all the records for a given category are stored contiguously (relatively) on the disk, resulting in less number of disk pages to be retrieved.  This is also because of smaller record size compared to that of table with all categories as columns. The advantage is the flexibility to add more categories easily and the downside is repetition of (ID, TopicID) column data that affects the total size of the data.
2. If you retrieve by topic, then I would go with the first approach, defining an index on the topic. This would reduce the repetition of (ID, TopicID) column values for each category, thereby reducing the total size of the data to be stored and since the count of rows is in millions per hour, this reduction in size must be significant. The downside is the need to modify the schema for new categories.

**Edit**:
Considering the retrieval patterns from your edit:

> I retrieve top topics and their values per Category so i order by votes_Category_x in case 1.

I understand this as `Find the top N topics with largest number of votes in a given category`

> In case 2 I would look to find max(category) for each topic_id.

and this as `SELECT TopicID, MAX(votes) FROM TABLE GROUP BY TopicID, Category`.

The size of the record is different for 2million and 24million rows, but yes, the ID and TopicID are repeated which would definitely increase the data size, by 8 bytes for each record.

The first table stores 2 million records each of size `60 bytes (4*15 ints)` and the second table stores 24 million records each of size `16 bytes (4*4 ints)`. The second table would add `~62` pages of `4KB` each, per hour. Seems like a concern over a period of time. This will also affect the fragmentation due to insertion of data in the middle, as the index is organized by category in case of second approach.

It may be worth running some performance tests to understand this better and also weigh in the frequency of adding categories, before going ahead with one of the table structures.

Comment: @ntg, updated the response as per my understanding of your edit.

Comment: You got it right. I need the best 10 topics in each category. It surely is more flexible but I'm not sure how mysql will perform on 24 million rows (case 2) compared to 2 million rows (case 1)

Comment: ~ntg, you are discounting how performance degrades as you have a 14 field record vs a 3 field record.

Comment: @Marlin that's the question i'm asking. which one would be faster. I'm really not sure how will that work when users go tho the scoreboard often. (i think about some caching but still the question stands)

Comment: @ntg, tried doing some math around the table structures and updated my response.

Comment: @Vikdor category names are not relevant. In case 1. there will be just 12 columns for them with the count of the votes they collect. In case 2: they will be id of category and another column for vote count

Comment: @ntg, my bad, I was counting category column in first approach as varchars though they hold integer counts. Thanks for pointing out. The columns being integers every where, the difference in number of database pages remains the same, per hour, which could be a concern.

Comment: @Vikdor thank you for the math. Do you think there is something other than the size of the tables that will mess with the performance. The point from Marlin in the comments about how performance degrades because of column number. Too bad he didn't elaborate on it more cuz i have no real clue about it

Comment: @ntg, You can save on the record size, i.e. column count, if you are not interested in all the columns during retrieval and you go with vertical partitioning where you move out columns-of-no-interest to a separate table to reduce the record size, thereby the number of database pages that the entire table spans. This is relevant if you have many varchar columns in your table structure. But in your case, all the columns are of integer type and storing the count by category in separate row is adversely affecting the size of your table on the whole. So, one category per row seems costly.

Comment: @Vikdor all 12 (for now) categories are important and used for the different topics. In case 2: I wonder if using Max on votes (where category_id=x and topic_id=y) will be slower than in case 1: Order by categoy_x where topic_id=y

Comment: It may be slower in case 2 as the index would be defined on category where it may be faster in case 1 as the index would be defined on topic_id.

Comment: btw, you may want to post this in http://dba.stackexchange.com to see what the DBA experts would say.